# unable to get the user input to the flask route

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I have pdf file which contains speed and time data when user uploads pdf file the code convert pdf file to pandas data frame and it does some calculations for finding acceleration counts. i am able to upload pdf file and perform calculation but my problem is based on user inputs the flask route has to take user inputs and perform calculation based on user inputs and give the result. for uploading there is no error after uploading the file and filled form data by clicking submit unable to get result
here is my python app.py code for uploading file and calculations

```
application= Flask(__name__)
application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
global dfw
application.secret_key = "super secret key"
application.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        lower_limit = int(request.form.get('lower_limit', 0))
        upper_limit = int(request.form.get('upper_limit', 0))
        lines = []
        with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
            pages = pdf.pages
            for page in pdf.pages:
                text = page.extract_text()
                for line in text.split('\n'):
                    lines.append(line)
                    print(line)
        df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
        df.drop([0, 1, 2, 3], inplace=True)
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df.astype(str)
        df1= df[0].str.extract(r'(\d*)\ (\d*:\d*:?\d* [AMP ].) (\d*)')
        df1.columns = ["S.No", "Time", "Speed"]
        df2 = df1[df1["Speed"].str.contains("Speed") == False]
        cols = df2.columns.drop('Time')
        df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
        fig=px.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(name='Time',x=df2["Time"],y=df2["Speed"], line_color='red')])
        op_col = []
        for i in df2['Speed']:
            op_col.append(i)
        np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
        x = np.array(op_col)
        x1 = x.astype('int32')
        def get_count1():
            sub_lists = np.split(x1, np.where(np.diff(x1) < 0)[0] + 1)
            id_count1 = 0
            id_list1 = []
            for unit in sub_lists:
                if min(unit) <= lower_limit and max(unit) > upper_limit  and len(set(unit)) > 1:
                    id_count1 += 1
                    id_list1.append(unit)
            return id_count1
            id_count1 = get_count1()
            print(id_count1)
        graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
        return render_template('index.html', graphJSON=graphJSON,shape=df2.shape,count_result1=get_count1(), titles=[''])
    return render_template('index.html')
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
```

the pdf file which i am uploading is [this](https://online.flippingbook.com/view/768373912/)

here is my html code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-UQiGfs9ICog+LwheBSRCt1o5cbyKIHbwjWscjemyBMT9YCUMZffs6UqUTd0hObXD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

<h1 style="background-color:#08F3F7;">Acceleration Count using Speed and Time Data</h1>
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileInput">
    <!-- No Upload button needed -->
</form>
<div id="selectedFileName"></div>
  <div class="form-container">
    <p><b>Acceleration counts for selected vehicle</b></p>
    <form id="count-form">
      <label for="lower_limit">Lower Limit:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lower_limit" name="lower_limit" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <br>
      <label for="upper_limit">Upper Limit :</label>
      <input type="text" id="upper_limit" name="upper_limit" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
    <br>
    <p><b>The acceleration count is {{id_count}}</b></p>
  </div>
```

my expected output is after uploading the file when user enters the lower_limit and upper_limit values it has to show the id_count but nothing is displaying